# problem implementing wicked pdf on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, pdf-generation, production-environment, wicked-pdf

I am using [this guide](https://github.com/jordan-brough/heroku-pdf) for integrating wicked_pdf on heroku. But somehow it doesn't seem to work. I got the logs from heroku and its says this:

```
Processing PdfController#get_pdf to pdf (for 115.248.175.50 at 2011-02-15 23:54:44) [GET]
  Parameters: {"format"=>"pdf", "action"=>"get_pdf", "id"=>"1", "controller"=>"pdf"}
***************WICKED***************
Rendering pdf/get_pdf

RuntimeError (PDF could not be generated!
/usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/1.8/open3.rb:73:in `exec': No such file or directory - /app/fa369291-829b-4b61-9efe-b2f0d0a0a42c/home/bin/wkhtmltopdf-amd64       - -  (Errno::ENOENT)
    from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/1.8/open3.rb:73:in `popen3'
    from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/1.8/open3.rb:59:in `fork'
    from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/1.8/open3.rb:59:in `popen3'
    from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/1.8/open3.rb:57:in `fork'
    from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/1.8/open3.rb:57:in `popen3'
    from /app/fa369291-829b-4b61-9efe-b2f0d0a0a42c/home/vendor/plugins/wicked_pdf/lib/wicked_pdf.rb:22:in `pdf_from_string'
    from /app/fa369291-829b-4b61-9efe-b2f0d0a0a42c/home/vendor/plugins/wicked_pdf/lib/pdf_helper.rb:28:in `make_pdf'
    from /app/fa369291-829b-4b61-9efe-b2f0d0a0a42c/home/vendor/plugins/wicked_pdf/lib/pdf_helper.rb:39:in `make_and_send_pdf'
    from /app/fa369291-829b-4b61-9efe-b2f0d0a0a42c/home/vendor/plugins/wicked_pdf/lib/pdf_helper.rb:13:in `render'
    from /app/fa369291-829b-4b61-9efe-b2f0d0a0a42c/home/app/controllers/schedule_controller.rb:33:in `get_pdf'
```

Please Help. Thanks in Advance.

**EDIT:**

I made some changes in my code and got through this error but still stuck here

`NoMethodError (undefined method empty? for #<Pathname:0x2b7112392480>)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After looking at your Edit part which says "undefined method empty? for `#<Pathname:0x2b...>`

This means you are somewhere using empty? function on a path Object whereas empty? is a function of a string and not path.

try to find out where you have used a path Object and use to_s on that object.

Try it out.

Comment: you can refer 
http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html
and
http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/pathname/rdoc/index.html

Comment: Thanks, actually in the wicked_pdf config file I was using `Rails.root.join('bin', 'wkhtmltopdf-amd64')` and this was giving me the `PATH` object added `to_s` to it, and it worked

Answer (score 42):

**How to get WickedPdf gem to work on Heroku**

(see citation below for urls)

1. Create a folder named `bin` in the root of your Rails app.
2. Download and extract version **0.9.9** of the `wkhtmltopdf` binaries to the `bin` folder. You will need the version for your development system and the AMD64 version for Heroku. Do *not* add to your git repo yet.
3. Set the execute permissions for each binary in the `bin` folder e.g. `chmod +x bin/wkhtmltopdf-amd64`
4. Now `git add bin`
5. Add `wicked_pdf` to your `Gemfile` and `bundle install`. No other wkhtmltopdf gems are needed.
6. Create a file in the `config/initializers` folder called `wicked_pdf.rb` with the source code below.
7. `git commit -am 'added wkhtmltopdf binaries and wicked_pdf gem'`
8. `git push heroku`

Your Rails project is now configured for Heroku. From here, add your program logic for PDF files.

** config/initializers/wicked_pdf.rb **

```
if Rails.env.production?
  wkhtmltopdf_path = "#{Rails.root}/bin/wkhtmltopdf-amd64"
else
  # Linux (check your processor for Intel x86 or AMD x64)
  # wkhtmltopdf_path = "#{Rails.root}/bin/wkhtmltopdf-amd64"
  # wkhtmltopdf_path = "#{Rails.root}/bin/wkhtmltopdf-i386"
  # OS X
  wkhtmltopdf_path = "#{Rails.root}/bin/wkhtmltopdf-0.9.9-OS-X.i386"            
  # Windows
  # wkhtmltopdf_path = 'C:\Program Files/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf.exe'
end

WickedPdf.config = { exe_path: wkhtmltopdf_path, wkhtmltopdf: wkhtmltopdf_path }
```

**How I came to this conclusion:**

For starters, there are SEVERAL misleading articles on the Web regarding `wkhtmltopdf`, the `wicked_pdf` gem, and `Heroku`. 
There are also issues with recent versions of `wkhtmltopdf` (10.0+) that cause execution to hang.

Lastly, at some point there must have been a change in the config variable names for `WickedPdf` because several articles reference `:exe_path` while other articles reference `:wkhtmltopdf`. 
Even WickedPdf's GitHub documentation alternates between each variable.

My solution you do *not* need to compile `wkhtmltopdf` from source.
You do *not* need to install `wkhtmltopdf` from Homebrew. I provided the solution to this if you really want to `brew install wkhtmltopdf`.
You also do *not* need to add any of the 'wkhtmltopdf' *helper* gems to your project. I tried `wkhtmltopdf`, `wkhtmltopdf-heroku`, `wkhtmltopdf-engineyard`, `wkhtmltopdf-binary` gems and GitHub repos. Worked great locally. No luck at Heroku.

From a Rails console on Heroku:
I investigated what CPU was running Heroku's servers by running `RUBY_PLATFORM` which yielded `"x86_64-linux"`.
I also peeked inside the `bin` folder on Heroku by issuing the `Dir.entries('bin')` to see what files actually exist there. I noticed some of the `wkhtmltopdf` gems I was testing placed their executables in this folder. A clue!
I ran `WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string('Hello')` to see the output errors and test various WickedPdf configurations.

Then, in @barlow's answer to configuring `PDFKit`, there is a subnote that gave the ultimate key. You *must* give Unix execute permissions to `wkhtmltopdf` the binary before committing to Git. Bingo!

Cite:

1. Official wkhtmltopdf legacy static binaries http://wkhtmltopdf.org/old-downloads.html
2. wicked_pdf https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf
3. Barlow's PDFKit.config https://stackoverflow.com/a/5098984/307308
4. How to install wkhtmltopdf using Homebrew `https://stackoverflow.com/a/14043085/307308

At the time of this writing:

- rails (3.2.13)
- wicked_pdf (0.9.6)
- wkhtmltopdf (0.9.9)

**Amended 2/12/2015**

[dscout](http://dscout.com) has developed a gem that encompasses the concepts of my answer. I recommend using the gem if your Heroku instance supports buildpacks.

- https://github.com/dscout/wkhtmltopdf-buildpack
- https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks

**Amended 3/27/2015**

Another gem that works with Heroku (and Linux AMD64 OSes) [wkhtmltopdf-heroku](https://github.com/rposborne/wkhtmltopdf-heroku)
It auto-detects if pdfkit, wicked_pdf and wisepdf gems are installed.

Comment: Clear, concise answer. Worked first time for me. Many thanks.

Comment: As an update, using the following worked first time on Heroku: Rails 4.1.6, wicked_pdf 0.11.0 and wkhtmltopdf-binary 0.9.9.3

Comment: How did you get the AMD64 binary? All I see are Linux packages. I extracted the .deb archive and it looks like there are linked dependencies instead of an all inclusive standalone binary.

Comment: @Dex Thank you for bringing this to my attention. The statics were moved to this location: http://wkhtmltopdf.org/old-downloads.html  I updated the citation to the new url 2/11/2015.

Comment: Thanks for that. I just tried using this build pack and it seems to work: https://github.com/dscout/wkhtmltopdf-buildpack

Comment: Thanks @Dex. I added that info to my answer.

Comment: a gem packed with a executable seems to work, too: https://github.com/rposborne/wkhtmltopdf-heroku

Comment: Thanks @juanitofatas. I'm glad to see rposborne has updated the wkhtmltopdf-heroku gem to a recent version of the wkhtmltopdf library. I've added the reference to my answer.

Comment: @scarver2 typo in wicked_pdf.rb? "i368" instead of "i386"

Answer (score 3):

If you add a local copy of wkhtmltopdf to your repo you can point to it like this in an initializer.

```
PDFKit.configure do |config|
config.wkhtmltopdf = "#{RAILS_ROOT}/lib/wkhtmltopdf"
end
```

remember to chmod +x your wkhtmltopdf copy in your repo before you - git add it

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry, so used to using PDFkit I see wkhtmltopdf and I straight away think PDFkit,

Comment: Maybe PDFkit is the Answer your actually looking for?

Comment: No, I need to use wicked_pdf :)

Answer (score 0):

Is looking for the wicked_pdf binary in : `/app/fa369291-829b-4b61-9efe-b2f0d0a0a42c/home/bin/wkhtmltopdf-amd64`

And is not there, put the binary in a folder within your application and then change the file `config/initializers/wicked_pdf.rb` to include:

```
:exe_path => "#{Rails.root}/path/to/wkhtmltopdf-amd64"
```

Another problem you might come to if wicked_pdf create files, is the fact that Heroku filesystem is only read, so unless you find a way to tell wicked_pdf to create the pdfs in the tmp directory you might not be able to use it.

Comment: Thanks. But I have already done that the binary exists in my `RAILS_ROOT/bin/` and in the `config/initializers/wicked_pdf.rb` I have specified `:exe_path => Rails.root.join('bin', 'wkhtmltopdf-amd64').to_s` but it still doesn't work

Comment: Your answer seems legit. Could it be something with the platform type of the binary? I ran RUBY_PLATFORM from a Heroku console and got `=> "x86_64-linux"` as the response.