# wicked_pdf fails to produce a PDF report once deployed on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, wicked-pdf

I am trying to generate PDF reports with wicked_pdf gem.
THe PDF generation works fine on my development environment, but it fails once it's deployed on Heroku

This is the error I am getting:

```
Failed to execute:
 /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/bin/wkhtmltopdf --header-font-name 'Century Gothic' --header-left 'My Test - Neuffen, Germany' --header-right '2012-02-05 15:50:57 -0800' --header-font-size 14 --header-line  --footer-center 'Generated by Biowatts - http://biowatts.org' --footer-font-name 'Century Gothic' --footer-font-size 13 --footer-line   --toc-font-name 'Century Gothic' --toc-disable-links  --toc-disable-back-links     --orientation 'Landscape' --no-background    -q - - 
Error: PDF could not be generated!
 .bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/wicked_pdf-0.7.2/lib/wicked_pdf.rb:39:in `rescue in pdf_from_string'
```

Any idea how to address this issue?

20120207 - Additional attemps

When adding these to my gem file, I get a diffenret error:

```
group :production do
   gem "wkhtmltopdf-heroku", :git => 'git://github.com/camdez/wkhtmltopdf-heroku.git'  
end
```

The Error:

```
Location of wkhtmltopdf unknown
  .bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/wicked_pdf-0.7.2/lib/wicked_pdf.rb:20:in `initialize'
```

Comment: Ok I tried to improve the description text. Still I don't understand the overzealous -1? Also I'd be grateful to have my question reopened.

Comment: I voted for reopening. I do not quite understand why it is closed. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Work around only and use another gem. gem "pdfkit", "~> 0.5.2" but ended up with a compatibility problem with Rails 3.1 assets. It's fixed in 3.2 apparently. This video helped a lot http://railscasts.com/episodes/220-pdfkit and you need to add wkhtmltopdf binary to your-project/app/bin

Comment: Ok. I got it to work with wicked-pdf and the wkhtmltopdf-heroku gem. But good you found a solution.

Comment: I'd still be interested if/when you have the time to punch a few lines on how you had it fixed. I liked wicked_pdf. Cheers

Comment: Since I can't answer here, I wrote a small blogpost about it: http://www.dixis.com/?p=634 It turned out to be incredibly easy.

Comment: Check out my answer to this here http://stackoverflow.com/a/16577677/307308  It works perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

Are you using proper wkhtmltopdf library?
Something like this one:

```
group :production do
  gem "wkhtmltopdf-heroku", :git => 'git://github.com/camdez/wkhtmltopdf-heroku.git'
end
```

Comment: this didn't work now I get a different error. See Edits in my oringal post