# Using Wkhtmltopdf with Nodejs on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, wkhtmltopdf

Here is the thing. I'm on nodejs and I want to generate a PDF file with wkhtmltopdf.
It works fine locally, but when I push it on heroku I have an "Application Error".

I think it's because it's missing a binary Wkhtmltopdf for Heroku, do you know one?
Or is it something else?

Comment: Did you check the heroku logs to make sure the missing 'wkhtmltopdf' is causing the App error? I have used the 'wkhtmltoimage' from https://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/downloads/list on Heroku via ImageMagik and it works fine. I would imagine that Wkhtmltopdf would work too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heroku doesn't include the `wkhtmltopdf` binary, but you have two options to get it working there.

First is to [**build `wkhtmltopdf` from source on Heroku**](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpack-binaries) (using the [Vulcan gem](https://github.com/heroku/vulcan)).

The second is to directly bundle `wkhtmltopdf` with your app. Read through [this](https://gist.github.com/wrburgess/3778949), [this](http://www.mobalean.com/blog/2011/08/02/pdf-generation-and-heroku) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5013955/problem-implementing-wicked-pdf-on-heroku/16577677#16577677) for guidance. Essentially, you have to downloading the binary executable into your app's `/bin` folder, push it to Heroku, and correctly configure `wkhtmltopdf`'s settings from within the app.

P.S. The examples I cited deal with Ruby, but they give a good overview of what needs to be set up for `wkhtmltopdf` to work on Heroku. There is a [sample Rails app](https://github.com/jordan-brough/heroku-pdf) pre-integrated with `wkhtmltopdf` for reference.