# is it possible to run an exe file on heroku?

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku

I want users to fill out an html form and when they submit the form they could print out a PDF with other information plus their answers. If you have any input on how to get that done, it would be great.

I was looking for a solution for this problem and I found [wkhtmltopdf.org](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/) it says to do `wkhtmltopdf http://google.com google.pdf` through the command prompt. I did it in the bin directory where wkhtmltopdf.exe is located.

I ended up getting the PDF of google. but this is on my PC. how do I get this exe on heroku? is there another way to solve this problem? I only know JS and work with windows.

Comment: I don't know why I got down voted. I would appreciate if someone can explain to me how to use tools like wkhtmltopdf on heroku. I'm trying to learn. Here, I think  is another example of having something installed on a machine for their package to work. https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdf-fill-form. You need to install Poppler QT4.  how do you do that on heroku?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Wkhtmltopdf with Nodejs on Heroku](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15118273/using-wkhtmltopdf-with-nodejs-on-heroku)